# First Schema for Location and Countries

Tags: sql, mysql

This is my first MYSQL schema for caching location data (co-ordinates to place names) and referencing it with a country.

I was wondering what everyones feedback was on it, did I do a good job?

```
CREATE TABLE location (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
locality VARCHAR(20),
administrative_area_level_1 VARCHAR(20),
administrative_area_level_2 VARCHAR(20),
administrative_area_level_3 VARCHAR(20),
loc VARCHAR (17) NOT NULL,
rad VARCHAR (17),
updated TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE country (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(20),
iso VARCHAR(20),
loc VARCHAR (17) NOT NULL,
rad VARCHAR (17),
updated TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: are these two tables linked? I don't see a Foreign key or anything to link the tables together. I do see 2 columns that have the same name in both tables?

Comment: Idem. Your query is ambiguous for Code Review. I would personally expect a `country.id` column as foreign key in `location` but may or may not be the case depending on your schema design.

Answer (score 2):

For all it's worth, and this is pretty old but for the sake of clearing unanswered reviews, here is my take:

- `id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,`

  I find that being more specific in column names makes the code easier to work with, especially when you are using `JOIN` and table aliases. Suppose the following:

  ```
  SELECT l.*, c.*
  FROM location AS l
  LEFT JOIN country AS c
  ON l.loc = c.loc
  ```

  The result set would have column headers as `l.id` and `c.id` unless you took the time to make column aliases for everything. If your columns were instead named `location_id` and `country_id` the result set would be much easier to read to someone who is not a database programmer.
- `name VARCHAR(20)`

  I think 20 may be a bit short for country name. For instance:

  ```
  SELECT CHAR_LENGTH('United States of America');
  ```

  Result: 24

Other than that I think it looks fine.